# C-Checking if input (float) is purely integer or float

Tags: c, function

I want to check if the user input is purely integer or a float. I attempted to do this by using `floor` and `ceilf`and comparing the values to the original x value in a function. However, this seems to be a tad bit problematic as the function keeps returning 0 instead of 1 for certain numbers like 5.5, when `floor(5.5)!=5.5` and `ceilf(5.5)!=5.5`. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
int intchecker(float x)//in a separate file
{

    if (floor(x)==x && ceilf(x)==x)
    {
        //printf("%f",floor(x));
        return 0;
    }
    else {
                return 1;
    }

}
int main()
{
    char line[] = " +----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+---+";
    char numbers[] = " 0    5    10   15   20   25   30   35   40   45   50";
    float balls,slots;
    int slot[9];

    printf("==========================================================\nGalton Box Simulation Machine\n==========================================================\n");
    printf("Enter the number of balls [5-100]: ");
    scanf("%f",& balls);
    if (balls>100 || balls<5){
        printf("/nInput is not within the range. Please try again.");
    }

    else if (intchecker(balls)==1){
        printf("/nInput is not an integer. Please try again.");
    }
    else {
            printf("    This is an integer.");
            //some more code here
    }

}
```

I tried placing just the intchecker code in another project, which seems to work fine without any bugs, unlike in the previous project, where when I used a `printf` statement to check if the `floor(x)` value was correct, it kept showing different answers, e.g. "-2.000000" when input was 5.2. This is my code for the second project:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{
    float  x;
    scanf("%f",&x);

    if (floor(x)==x && ceilf(x)==x){
        printf("Integer");
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        printf("Non-Integer");
        return 1;
    }


}
```

How is it possible that the second code works perfectly when the first code does not? Is something wrong with my way of writing/calling the function?(I am relatively new to functions-only 2 weeks of exposure so far)

I searched online and have seen many answers to check if input is integer or float, even on stackoverflow.com itself, but my wish is not to find out other ways to check if input is integer or float (for if I wished to do that, I could just google it, and there are many such questions on stackoverflow.com as well), but to comprehend **why** my first code does not work, for, as far as I know, it ought to work well without any of the bugs it is currently facing.

Any help is greatly appreciated!:)

Comment: If you require an integer value then why do you scan a `float` from the input?  Also either `floorf(x) == x` *or* `ceilf(x) == x` is sufficient; you don't need both.

Comment: *"I used a printf statement to check if the floor(x) value was correct, it kept showing different answers, e.g. "-2.000000" when input was 5.2."* You need to show the exact code that exhibits that behavior, because nothing in the code you posted would do that. My best guess is that your real code has a buffer overrun bug, or other undefined behavior.

Comment: are you giving the exact same input to both programs?   `scanf("%f",&myfloat)` of "5" may actually read in 5.0000000000000001, and "4" may be exactly 4.0.    it all depends on the implementation of scanf().

Comment: FYI A simple test to see if a `float` is a whole number or not: `float dummy; if (modff(x, &dummy) == 0.0) puts("x is a whole number");`

Comment: Are you always putting function `int intchecker(float x)` before `main()`?  Always including `#include <math.h>`?

Comment: Code interestingly uses `ceilf(float)` and `floor(double)`, yet not `floorf(float)`.  I suspect `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` is 1 or 2 and the `main()` code was optimized to `double`.  Does the difference occur if you code with `floorf()`?  What is `printf("%d\n", FLT_EVAL_METHOD);`?

Comment: Int intchecker(float x) is located in a file separate from main.c.

Comment: So does `main.c` have a prototype of `int intchecker(float x);`?  If not, then that is likely the issue.

Comment: A better approach to this problem would be to read a string (either with `scanf` or `fgets`) and see if there is a `.` in the string.  Then you can use `strtof` to convert the string to float if required.

Comment: @M.M Looking for a `'.'` is a good start but does get fooled with `"1.0"` and `"5e-1"`.

Comment: @RussSchultz: floating point isn't as evil as that.  Every integer from -2^54 to 2^54 has an exact representation as an IEEE double-precision float.  Similarly for `float`, +/- 2^24 in 23-bit-mantissa IEEE single float.  See some guys blog for just one example: http://cottonvibes.blogspot.ca/2010/08/32bit-floats-integer-accuracy-and.html.  Where people run into trouble is with decimal fractions that don't have an exact representation as a binary-fraction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming a missing function declaration:

`main.c` is missing the prototype for `int intchecker(float x)` so `main.c` assumes the old-school prototype of `int intchecker(int x)` and the code exhibits undefined behavior.  Anything could happen.

Add prototype in `main.c` or put it in separate.h and include that header file here and in separate.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int intchecker(float x);

int main(void) {
   ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The code works perfectly fine now after adding the prototype. I am not that familiar with functions and hence assumed that separate files would be read first automatically without any need for declaration. It seems like that was the error after all.

Comment: The header `.h`, containing `int intchecker(float x);` is commonly included in the `.c` implementation and all usage `.c` files.  The `.h` also contains defines, typdefs, global variable declarations.  All sorts of things that by themselves do not generate any code.   Like `<math.h>`, you will find lots of these things but no implementations.   Good luck on the journey.

Comment: @JaimeAlcaraz you should have received a compiler warning at least - pay attention to those messages!

Comment: Does it mean that if the prototype is not included, the code in the function is not read at all?

Comment: @JaimeAlcaraz  the code in the function is not "read" by `main.c`.  All `main.c` "reads" is in `main.c` and the various included files like `stdio.h` and `separate.h`.  All `separate.c` "reads" is in `separate.c` and its various included files like `math.h` and `separate.h`.  These 2 compilations (which could have occurs days apart) are then linked together as a final step.