# Error message: if the number is not integer but float

Tags: c, if-statement, scanf

Why the error does not occur when I put a float number?

```c
int m;
if(scanf("%d%",&m)!=1)
{
    printf("Error\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Depends on exactly how the "float" is given: For example, "1.2" can be (correctly) seen as an integer input (i.e. "1" - ignoring the rest); however, ".123" will most likely fail.

Comment: Maybe this post: [C-Checking if input (float) is purely integer or float](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32469222/10871073) will be helpful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `%d` will consume all decimal digits until the first non-decimal digit.  So if you enter `"50.5"` `m` will have the value 50 and the characters `".5"` will remain in the buffer unread.

There are many possible solutions.  Here's one:

```
int m ;
double fm ;

if( scanf("%f%",&fm) != 1 || 
    modf( fm, &m) != 0 )
{
    printf("Error\n");
    exit(1);
}
```